# MySQL Update column with statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to do something like the following

```
UPDATE table SET column = other_column IN(complex_statement)
```

My question is whether this wold cause the complex statement to be evaluated for each row or not, which would obviously not very good for performance.

The alternative would be doing

```
UPDATE table SET column = 0;
UPDATE table SET column = 1 WHERE other_column IN(complex_statement)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on whether the "other Complex statement" is a "Correlated" subquery or not.. A "Correlated" subquery is one where the results depend on the value of the row in the "outer" query.

So, if the complex statement has a reference to a column on your outer query table, then it is a "Correlated" subquery and the answer would be yes, it will be evaluated foreach row.  Otherwise, No.

Comment: thanks, in my case it#s not a correlated subquery so I should be fine